# Необходимо ли освобождать интерфейс COM который был получен с помощью QueryInterface

Tags: c++, com, directx

Делаю обертку над некоторыми из объектов `DirectX`, дошло дело до копирования из другого объекта `DirectX` т.е. преобразование из `DirectX` объекта в объект моего типа. У каждого из таких объектов есть метод `QueryInterface`, далее, я запрашиваю интересующий меня интерфейс у данного объекта и провожу некоторые действия с ним. По моему мнению другой объект из которого был создан объект у которого я запросил интерфейс, кол-во ссылок должно увеличиться, и для предотвращения утечек памяти, я должен вызвать `Release` для объекта который я запросил.

Правильно ли так делать, и вообще нужно ли?

```
HRESULT result = ptr->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_render_target_));
if(result != S_OK)
{
    throw std::exception("Failed to QueryInterface from ID2D1SolidColorBrush");
}

result = m_render_target_->CreateSolidColorBrush(ptr->GetColor(), &m_solid_color_brush_ptr_);

if (result != S_OK)
{
    throw std::exception("Failed to CreateSolidColorBrush from ID2D1HwndRenderTarget");
}

m_solid_color_brush_ptr_->SetOpacity(ptr->GetOpacity());

D2D1_MATRIX_3X2_F matrix;
memset(&matrix, 0, sizeof matrix);
ptr->GetTransform(&matrix);
m_solid_color_brush_ptr_->SetTransform(matrix);
```

Для `m_render_target_` локального поля, я должен вызвать `Release` в деструкторе, а в обычном конструкторе добавить ссылку вызвав `AddRef`, т.к. в обычный конструктор передается указатель на этот объект?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, вызов `QueryInterface` увеличивает внутренний счетчик ссылок объекта, поэтому у успешно полученного указателя следует вызвать `Release`. Однако делать это все руками не следует, благо это все уже реализовано в умных указателях, например `WRL::ComPtr`:

```
::Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<::ID3D11Device> p_d3d_device{};
// создаем D3D устройство...
::Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<::IDXGIDevice> p_dxgi_device{};
if(!SUCCEEDED(p_d3d_device.As(&p_dxgi_device))) // тут вызовется `QueryInterface`
{ /* обработка ошибки */  }
// при выходе из области видимости у каждого указателя будет вызван `Release`
```

Answer (score 2):

Правило очень простое, `AddRef` и `Release` должны быть строго симметричны. И да, корректный `QueryInterface` в случае успеха, должен вызывать `AddRef` для объекта. Поэтому после завершения работы с вашими интерфейсами, вы должны вызвать `Release` и все.

Офтоп. Второе исключение которое вы бросаете выглядит опасно, не забыли ли вы что `m_render_target` уже получен и нуждается в заботе.

Comment: Хорошее замечание, но это пример конструктора =)

Comment: @Yami O-o, что!? Сообщаю вам, что если исключение брошено из конструктора, то парный ему деструктор вызван не будет! Так как конструирование объекта не завершено. Учите матчасть.

Comment: Вы меня не так поняли, это пример конструктора накиданный на скорую руку, в реальной реализации объект освобождается.

Comment: Извините, пусть коментарий останется для потомков.